# How to extract a hyper link which satisfies a condition in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have extract the page source information through R

```
download.file("http://stats.espncricinfo.com/ci/engine/records/team/match_results_year.html?class=2;id=6;type=team",
              "dataDictionary.html")
docHtml = htmlTreeParse("dataDictionary.html", useInternal = TRUE) # to Download the page source 
links <- xpathSApply(docHtml,path = "//a", xmlGetAttr, "href")
```

now I need to extract data which has something like `"/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html?class=2;id= *"` . Here `*` in the sense whatever satisfies this condition those data.s has to be stored in another variable. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

All of the links you are interested in can be detected with `grep`

```
GoodLinks = grep("/ci/engine/records/team/match_results.html\\?class=2;id", links)
```

If you only want the id field,  you can process those links with `sub`

```
sub(".*id=(\\d+).*", "\\1", links[GoodLinks])
[1] "1974" "1975" "1976" "1978" "1979" "1980" "1981" "1982" "1983" "1984" "1985" "1986" "1987" "1988" "1989" "1990"
[17] "1991" "1992" "1993" "1994" "1995" "1996" "1997" "1998" "1999" "2000" "2001" "2002" "2003" "2004" "2005" "2006"
[33] "2007" "2008" "2009" "2010" "2011" "2012" "2013" "2014" "2015" "2016" "2017"
```